# EditText , want to appear typed text as stars ' * '

Tags: java, android, kotlin

is there any way to convert text to star '*' especially passwords when we type text in Edit Text filed .

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `EditText` XML

```xml
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Comment: Thank you friend , it work fine

Comment: There are also other types like `numberPassword` @AungPhyoZaw in case if you just want a numerical password or something.

Comment: I see a lot of options under the type android:inputType=" ", thank for your guidance

Comment: @AungPhyoZaw Yeah they are for different types. Keyboard suggestions popup according to the type you define like if it is email, then keyboard would show "@" symbol at top.

Answer (score 1):

`EditText` has the built in attribute `android:inputType` which allows you to set the type of input that the the field is accepting.

For instance if you set it to `android:inputType="phone"` then the keyboard will only display characters related to making a phonecall.

You can also set it to `android:inputType="textPassword"` which will then cause the field to automatically take care of obscuring the input when the user types into it.

You can find more detail in the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style#Type) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: Wow...... thank for instant answer , it is working.

Comment: Your welcome @AungPhyoZaw. Selecting answers as the accepted one will make it clear to others that there are solutions here to your question, so might I suggest you do so.